# Distribute number randomly into bins

Tags: python

I want to distribute a number randomly into different bins. What I'm doing at the moment is this:

```
import random

red = 0
blue = 0
green = 0
yellow = 0

for _ in range(n):
    t = random.randrange(4)
    if (t == 0):
        red += 1
    elif (t == 1):
        blue += 1
    elif (t == 2):
        green += 1
    else:
        yellow += 1
```

This does what I want (I think), but it looks almost ridiculously convoluted. I was wondering whether there was something better.
I tried

```
random.choice([red, blue, green, yellow])+=1
```

but of course this doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set up a list of 4 zeroes, modify it based on the random index, then unpack into the 4 variables you want.

```
import random

bins = [0, 0, 0, 0]

for _ in range(n):
    bins[random.randrange(4)] += 1

red, blue, green, yellow = bins
```

If you have more "variables", you could use [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which is dict-like:

```
import random
import collections

counts = collections.Counter()
things = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux", "spam", "eggs", "hernekeitto", "viina", "teline", "johannes"]

for _ in range(n):
    counts[random.choice(things)] += 1

print(counts.most_common())  # Handy!
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary of counts:

```
import random

counts = { 'red' : 0, 'blue' : 0, 'green' : 0, 'yellow' : 0 }
keys = [k for k in counts.keys()]

n = 100
for _ in range(n):
    counts[random.choice(keys)] += 1
    
print(counts)
```

Sample output:

```
{'red': 30, 'blue': 21, 'green': 28, 'yellow': 21 }
```

Comment: the OP wants to increment the variables not the keys which are infact strings in your solution.

Comment: @sage07 This is intended as an *alternative* to four separate variables, `red`, `blue`, etc; where OP would use `red` with this solution they would use `counts['red']`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this, if you prefer a one-liner:

```
red, blue, green, yellow = (random.randrange(n) for _ in range(4))
```

EDIT:
My answer is actually not correct for the problem at hand since the sum of all colors has to be "n" (which is not necessarily the case with my method).

Better (correct) solution, still a one-liner:

```
import numpy as np
n=100
red, blue, green, yellow = np.unique(np.random.randint(0,4,n),return_counts=True)[1]
```